# Namespace's don't make sense to me

Tags: c++, namespaces

Suppose I have the following defined in a header file:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   Class global_c;
}
```

Then I do this in a source file:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   void MyClass::Function( )
   {
       ::global_c.DoSomething( );
   }
}
```

global_c turns out as undefined by the compiler, if I do just global_c.DoSomething( ); however it compiles fine, if I add 'using namespace MyNamespace;' to the top of the file it also works fine.

Since global_c lives in the same namespace as 'MyClass' why can't it be resolved just because '::' is added to the front of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you are explicitly telling the compiler to use the global namespace by prepending the variable with `::`.  As `global_c` does not exist in the global namespace it throws an error.

The compiler is just doing what you told it to do.  Think of `::` as `Global::`.

Comment: If that is what it's doing then how come it can find it still? Shouldn't it still fall through because it's looking for it in the global namespace and not namespace MyNamespace?

Comment: @meds: What do you mean? It certainly does not work if you prepend it with `::`.  If you leave that out then it uses the current namesapce (`MyNamespace`).

Comment: S What I mean is if you prepend it with '::' and have 'using namespace MyNamespace' in the source file the compiler will be able to find the variable, does this just mean that when it looks for the variable in the global namespace it checks the 'using' namespaces too and not just global namespaces?

Comment: @meds: It can find it in that instance because you have imported all of `MyNamespace` into the global namespace.  That's what `using SomeNamespace` does.